# ASP.Net MVC - Dynamically Creating GridView and Binding Data to It in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I want to create GridView and its columns dynamically according to the datatable returned. So, I returned the datatable to the aspx file through ViewData and iterate the columns of datatable to create a GridView template. Then, using C# in aspx to bind the datatable to the GridView. But when I try to get the GridView in the aspx file, error message "The name XXX does not exist in the current context" is displayed. Any other way to achieve what I want to do?

The followings are my source code:

Controller

```
public ActionResult gridViewPage() {
    DataTable dt = runSqlQueryToReturnADataTable();
    ViewData["DT"] = dt;
    ViewData["DisplayMode"] = "Grid";
    return View();
}
```

ASPX File

```
<% if ("Grid".Equals(ViewData["DisplayMode"])) { %>
    <asp:GridView ID="gridViewForQuery" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <% foreach (System.Data.DataColum col in (ViewData["DT"] as System.Data.DataTable).Columns) %>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="<%: col.ColumnName %>"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <% gridViewForQuery.DataSource = (ViewData["DT"] as System.Data.DataTable); gridViewForQuery.DataBind(); %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You can directly set datatable and set AutoGeneratedColumn=True of GridView then it will automatically create columns that Database has.

Answer (score 0):

if you define grid depend any condition , you can not access from codebehind.

change gridview definition to this.

```
<% if ("Grid".Equals(ViewData["DisplayMode"])) {
   gridViewForQuery.DataSource = (ViewData["DT"] as System.Data.DataTable); gridViewForQuery.DataBind();
 }%>
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ID="gridViewForQuery" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution does solve the problem! But another problem arise. Error message "Control 'gridViewForQuery' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." Does it mean that I can only assign datasource and bind data at code behind? Any other solution? Thank you!

Comment: I updated post. and check this for runat="server" error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21554229/4172872